# How to resolve warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules

Tags: c

```
    #define HTON_I32(x) htonl(x)
inline float  __HTON_F32(float  x)
{
    int i = HTON_I32(*((int *)(&x)));
    return (*((float *)(&i)));
}
```

How to resolve warning `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules` 
in the above code

Comment: You could compile with the -fno-strict-aliasing flag on.  This will remove warnings about strict aliasing problems

Comment: @TonyTheLion: that doesn't resolve the problem, it hides it, and hides other potential problems in the code. Not a good idea.

Comment: @Mat, no, this resolves the problem at an optimization cost.

Comment: @Simon: it does not resolve the problem in case of different alignment requirements for `float` and `int`; this should not be a problem on mainstream architectures, but needlessly writing non-portable code should be frowned upon if reasonable portable alternatives exist...

Answer (score 9):

Eliminate the type-punning, and replace it with something that isn't fragile in the face of aliasing:

```
#include <string.h>

inline float __HTON_F32(float x) {
    int i;
    memcpy(&i, &x, sizeof x);
    i = HTON_I32(i);
    memcpy(&x, &i, sizeof x);
    return x;
}
```

Reasonable optimizing compilers will lower the `memcpy` calls, and generate equivalent (sometimes better) code to what you get from type-punning.

Another common solution you will see involves unions.  All of these solutions assume that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`.  You may want to add an assert to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unions for type-punning, which takes care of possible alignment and aliasing issues (C99:TC3 explicitly mentions that this is indeed legal):

```
#include <stdint.h>

inline float __HTON_F32(float x) {
    union { float as_float; int32_t as_int; } value = { x };
    value.as_int = HTON_I32(value.as_int);
    return value.as_float;
}
```

Comment: For anyone who wants the TC3 reference, this is in §6.5.2.3, footnote 82

Comment: ...and footnote 95 of the same section of the C1x April draft ;)

Comment: what does  this exactly do . ? value.as_int = HTON_I32(value.as_int);

Comment: I think the value of value.as_int is  garbage value.

Comment: why we have to assign int varibale HToN_I32(int)

Comment: previously they are doing int i = HTON_I32(*((int *)(&x)));.

Comment: assigning float to int. but now it seems are we assigning int to int with the below code

Comment: value.as_int = HTON_I32(value.as_int);

Comment: @Cristoph How does these unions work, you store as_int and then retrieve as_float? as_float does not contain anything?